# How exactly stream.Transform works in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, constructor, prototype

Below is a code snippet I found online on a blog which entails a simple example in using the stream Transform class to alter data streams and output the altered result. There are some things about this that I don't really understand.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

// node v0.10+ use native Transform, else polyfill
var Transform = stream.Transform ||
  require('readable-stream').Transform;
```

Why does the program need to check if the this var points to an instance of the Upper constructor? The Upper constructor is being used to construct the upper object below, so what is the reason to check for this? Also, I tried logging options, but it returns null/undefined, so what's the point of that parameter?

```
function Upper(options) {
  // allow use without new
  if (!(this instanceof Upper)) {
    return new Upper(options);
  }
```

I assume that this Transform.call method is being made to explicitly set the this variable? But why does the program do that, seeing as how Transform is never being called anyway.

```
  // init Transform
  Transform.call(this, options);
}
```

After googling the util package, I know that it is being used here to allow Upper to inherit Transform's prototypal methods. Is that right?

```
util.inherits(Upper, Transform);
```

The function below is what really confuses me. I understand that the program is setting a method on Upper's prototype which is used to transform data being input into it. But, I don't see where this function is being called at all!

```
Upper.prototype._transform = function (chunk, enc, cb) {
  var upperChunk = chunk.toString().toUpperCase();
  this.push(upperChunk);
  cb();
};


// try it out - from the original code
var upper = new Upper();
upper.pipe(process.stdout); // output to stdout
```

After running the code through a debugger, I can see that upper.write calls the aforementioned Upper.prototype._transform method, but why does this happen? upper is an instance of the Upper constructor, and write is a method that doesn't seem to have any relation to the _transform method being applied to the prototype of Upper.

```
upper.write('hello world\n'); // input line 1
upper.write('another line');  // input line 2
upper.end();  // finish
```

Answer (score 3):

First, if you haven't already, take a look at the Transform stream implementer's documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream).

- **Q:** Why does the program need to check if the this var points to an instance of the Upper constructor? The Upper constructor is being used to construct the upper object below, so what is the reason to check for this?
- **A:** It needs to check because anyone can call `Upper()` *without* `new`. So if it's detected that a user called the constructor without `new`, out of convenience (and to make things work correctly), `new` is implicitly called on the user's behalf.

---

- **Q:** Also, I tried logging options, but it returns null/undefined, so what's the point of that parameter?
- **A:** `options` is just a constructor/function parameter. If you don't pass anything to the constructor, then obviously it will be `undefined` (or whatever value you pass to it). You can have as many parameters as you want/need, just like any ordinary function. In the case of `Upper()` however, configuration isn't really needed due to the simplicity of the transform (just converting all input to uppercase).

---

- **Q:** I assume that this Transform.call method is being made to explicitly set the this variable? But why does the program do that, seeing as how Transform is never being called anyway.
- **A:** No, the `Transform.call()` allows the inherited "class" to perform its own initialization, such as setting up internal state variables. You can think of it as calling the `super()` in ES6 classes.

---

- **Q:** After googling the util package, I know that it is being used here to allow Upper to inherit Transform's prototypal methods. Is that right?
- **A:** Yes, that is correct. However, these days you can also use ES6 classes to do real inheritance. The [node.js stream implementers documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) shows examples of both inheritance methods.

---

- **Q:** The function below is what really confuses me. I understand that the program is setting a method on Upper's prototype which is used to transform data being input into it. But, I don't see where this function is being called at all!
- **A:** This function is called internally by node when it has data for you to process. Think of the method as being part of an interface (or a "pure virtual function" if you are familiar with C++) that you are required to implement in your custom Transform.

---

- **Q:** After running the code through a debugger, I can see that upper.write calls the aforementioned Upper.prototype._transform method, but why does this happen? upper is an instance of the Upper constructor, and write is a method that doesn't seem to have any relation to the _transform method being applied to the prototype of Upper.
- **A:** As noted in the [Transform documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream), Transform streams are merely simplified Duplex streams (meaning they accept input and produce output). When you call `.write()` you are writing to the Writable (input) side of the Transform stream. This is what triggers the call to `._transform()` with the data you just passed to `.write()`. When you call `.push()` you are writing to the Readable (output) side of the Transform stream. That data is what seen when you either call `.read()` on the Transform stream or you attach a `'data'` event handler.

Comment: mscdex - No, the Transform.call() allows the inherited "class" to perform its own initialization, such as setting up internal state variables. You can think of it as calling the super() in ES6 classes.

Do you think you can explain this in more detail? I'm not really sure what super() does to be honest.

Comment: @ZaidHumayun See MDN's [ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [`super()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) documentation for a more complete explanation. Hint: it calls the parent constructor.

Comment: Okay, so essentially what Transform.call(this, options) does is to call its own constructor, which is the stream.Transform object to help initialize an instance of the Upper function?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. `Transform()` is a constructor just like `Upper()` and as such it needs to do its own initialization. If you don't call it, then you will get errors when node tries to access internal state that isn't defined/initialized.